# How do static member Overloading and Overriding works in C++ structs?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Here is a an example code I saw in unreal engine recently.

The use case is the given structs form a hierarchy  keeps its "class id" in the hierarchy as a static integer field.

With helper functions as members to identify the struct's "Type" by comparing the ClassID Field.

These structs are intended to be always stored as object variables and never as pointers

```
struct ENGINE_API FDamageEvent
{

static const int32 ClassID = 0;

    virtual int32 GetTypeID() const { return FDamageEvent::ClassID; }
    virtual bool IsOfType(int32 InID) const { return FDamageEvent::ClassID == InID; };

}

struct ENGINE_API FPointDamageEvent : public FDamageEvent
{

    /** ID for this class. NOTE this must be unique for all damage events. */
    static const int32 ClassID = 1;
    virtual int32 GetTypeID() const override { return FPointDamageEvent::ClassID; };
    virtual bool IsOfType(int32 InID) const override { return (FPointDamageEvent::ClassID == InID) || FDamageEvent::IsOfType(InID); };

}

struct ENGINE_API FRadialDamageEvent : public FDamageEvent
{
    /** ID for this class. NOTE this must be unique for all damage events. */
    static const int32 ClassID = 2;

    virtual int32 GetTypeID() const override { return FRadialDamageEvent::ClassID; };
    virtual bool IsOfType(int32 InID) const override { return (FRadialDamageEvent::ClassID == InID) || FDamageEvent::IsOfType(InID); };

}
```

So the questions here are

1. Is `ClassID` field being reassigned, re-declared or shadowing in
       child structs?
2. Why does `GetTypeID`function uses explicit scope of itself while retrieving  `ClassID` despite being virtual?
3. Why does the `IsOfType` function in child struct
       calling parent class's `IsOfType` function ? Is it just to simulate
       polymorphism where each child is its parent type as well?

Comment: 1. it's overloaded; 2. style / semantics / clarity of intent; 3. clearly, yes

Comment: @paddy 1. shadowed, is it not?

Comment: @paddy does overloading here indicates that just using ```return ClassID;``` would work the same as would ```Object.ClassID```?

Comment: There is no 'static member overloading and overriding' here. There is overloading and overriding of *non*-static members, which is the only kind C++ supports.

Answer (score 2):

According to c++ standard **[class.derived.2]**:

> Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class.

This means **if you don't redeclare `classId` in derived class**, when you access it in the derived class, you are actually using the one of the base class.

However, in your case, you **did redeclare `classId`**. In this case, the `classId` of `baseClass` **is not considered a member** of the derived class, thus accessing `classId` in the derived class scope (without resolution qualifier `FDamageEvent::`) would be referring to `classId` you declared in your derived class.

You can call this name shadowing (`overloading` makes people think of functions).

**BUT REMEMBER: static variables are never involved in polymorphism!** (unless you are doing static polymorphism, then that would be another story). Polymorphism depends on instances, and static members **are not associated with any instances**! Accessing a static member using `.` or `->` on an instance (or pointer to instance) refer to the static variable of the instance's compile-time-type, not its polymorphic-type (**those two are different in c++**). Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct Base {
    static const int id = 0;
    virtual int get_id() const {
        return id;
    };
};

struct Derived : Base {
    static const int id = 1;
    int get_id() const override {
        return id;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* b = new Derived;
    std::cout << b->id << std::endl;        // Output: 0
    std::cout << b->get_id() << std::endl;  // Output: 1
    return 0;
}
```

As per question 2, usage of explicit scope is unnecessary here: `classId` and `FRadialDamageEvent::classId` are equivalent. It is just a matter of code taste. Some people prefer the latter for clarity.

As per question 3, I don't really understand the intent of this code. Imagine you have a multi-level inheritance hierarchy, for example `A -> B -> C` (`X -> Y` reads `Y derives from X`), then according to this method, an instance of `C` is not `B`, which is against conventional Object-Oriented pattern.

---

And about the keyword `override`: it is just a keyword to ensure that you are actually overriding a virtual method of the base class. You don't have to write `virtual` if you use `override`, because the latter already makes the function virtual. If the function isn't actually a virtual function in base class, then the compiler would emit an error: this prevents typos that declare new virtual methods than actually overriding one, and is more clear.

Comment: so if its essentially overloading the ```ClassID``` field would Object.ClassID respect polymorphism and return the same as ```ObjectPtr->GetTypeID()```

Also I guess the intent of calling parent class's ```IsOfType``` is just to simulate the case of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the `GetTypeId` compilations the `static const` class members are resolved as simple constants `0`, `1`, `2`.

```
FDamageEvent::GetTypeID() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
FPointDamageEvent::GetTypeID() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
FRadialDamageEvent::GetTypeID() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     eax, 2
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6SjG4T

```cpp
    int main(void)
    {
      FDamageEvent a;
      FPointDamageEvent b;
      FRadialDamageEvent c;

      std::cout
        << sizeof(a) << ' '
        << sizeof(b) << ' '
        << sizeof(c) << '\n';

      FDamageEvent &indirect_b = b;

      std::cout << "        B A&" << std::endl;
      std::cout
        << "B is A: " << b.IsOfType(a.GetTypeID())       << ' ' << indirect_b.IsOfType(a.GetTypeID()) << '\n'
        << "B is B: " << b.IsOfType(b.GetTypeID())       << ' ' << indirect_b.IsOfType(b.GetTypeID()) << '\n'
        << "B is C: " << b.IsOfType(c.GetTypeID())       << ' ' << indirect_b.IsOfType(c.GetTypeID()) << '\n';
    }
```

Output:

```
8 8 8
        B A&
B is A: 1 1
B is B: 1 1
B is C: 0 0
```

And using `sizeof` we could check that all types and instances have the same sizes.

> Why does the IsOfType function in child struct calling parent class's
>   IsOfType function ? Is it just to simulate polymorphism where each
>   child is its parent type as well?

Yes, the pattern `type == OwnType || SuperClass::isOfType(type)` is to simulate the entire multi-level checking:

`A is B is C is D`

`(type == D || (type == C || (type == B || (type == A))))`

Just override without call the `SuperClass::isOfType` will break the `is` expansion.